# Python slicing behavior using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a for loop to create a series from entries in a dataframe, however I am having difficulties getting the last element of the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
a.values[-1] # returns 7
a.values[-5:-1]# returns 3,4,5,6
a.values[-5:]# returns 3,4,5,6,7


b = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    b.append(a.values[-(i+1):-i])
```

I would like for 7 to be included in the list b. I realize that when i=0, a.values gives an empty array, however I'm not sure how to fix this as I can't iterate i to be blank as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just manually convert negative indices to positive indices?

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    b.append(a.values[(len(a) - (i+1) - 1):(len(a) - i)])
```

This works because python doesn't care if your upper limit in a slice is out-of-bounds, so long as the lower-limit is in bounds.

But if you're just trying to reverse the list (which it seems like you're trying to do), have you considered `b = reversed(a)`?

Answer (score 0):

> **I would like for 7 to be included in the list b**

`import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])`

`b = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    b.append(a.iloc[i])`

**OR, As a one-liner**:
`b = [a.iloc[i] for i in range(0, len(a))]`

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the blank and include 7 in the list:

`for i in range(0,len(a)):
    b.append(a.values[-i-1])`